# How to search array of json objects and return matching object using nlohmann-json

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

Imagine there is an array of account objects

```
[
    {"account_number":1,"customer_name":"John"}, 
    {"account_number":2,"customer_name":"Sally"}
]
```

I want to write a method that takes in an account number and returns the matching account object.  I initially came up with this

```
Account AccountDb::get_account(int account_number) {
for (auto &account_element : account_list_) {
    Account account = account_element;

    bool account_found = (account.account_number() == account_number);
    if (account_found) {
        return account;
    }
}

// no matching Account
return ???;
}
```

But I'm not sure that's a good way to do it especially since it wouldn't work if there was no matching account.  Any ideas how to tackle this?

I'm pretty new to c++ and I'm using nlohmann-json for my json parsing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Just use `std::optional` or throw an exception if the account isn't found

Comment: If you don't have `c++17` available, you can get away with returning `json()`, which creates a JSON `null` object. You can test this for nullity.